# React on Submit shows no data in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form in react which passes data to the console when the form is submitted.

Here is the code:

```
class myComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const formData = {};
        for (const field in this.refs) {
          formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
        }
        console.info('-->', formData);
      }

    render() {
      return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input ref="name" type="text" required />
                    <input ref="email" type="text"  required />
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  export default myComponent;
```

The problem I am having is that the console in not showing anything.

It's like handle Submit is not been triggered.

How can I fix this?

Comment: works here - https://codesandbox.io/s/j426jmyqq5

Comment: You can check if `this.handleSubmit` is being triggered with a `console.log("hello")` just below the function name. I think the problem lies in the for loop below the `formData` declaration. You're not filling `formData` with any info.

Comment: @Rodius I tried that and console.log("hello") didn't display anything :/

Comment: It works as expected, I think you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems fine and works as expected like the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j426jmyqq5) provided by [paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4425849/paul-fitzgerald) in the comment. Except the [naming convention provided by react](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized), that it should be started with Capitalized letter. Use the component name in capital letter:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
...
export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried it, your code is no problem:

[image]